# vb6 - send byte, the receive side get from 0 to 255

Tags: vb6

if i using VB6 to send the string (character) `a` through `WriteFile` (serial communication), the receive side will get `97` (reading byte), this is Dec value of `a`.

now i want the receiver side get the byte value from 0-255.

it's easy for some result, like:

send string `a`, get byte `97`. send string `z`, get byte `122`. but how to let receive get the byte value `0` or `1`?

how can i to realize this? i found vb6 `cbyte` function, but it seems not work properly. thank you.

here are my code current:

**send side (vb6):**

```
'this send the character "a"
call send_string(handle, "a")

Sub send_string(ByVal handle_connect As Long, ByVal s As String)
    WriteComm handle_connect, StrConv(s, vbFromUnicode)
End Sub

Function WriteComm(ByVal hComm As Long, BytesBuffer() As Byte) As Long
    Dim dwBytesWrite
       
    If SafeArrayGetDim(BytesBuffer) = 0 Then Exit Function
    WriteFile hComm, BytesBuffer(0), UBound(BytesBuffer) + 1, dwBytesWrite, 0
    WriteComm = dwBytesWrite
End Function
```

**receive side (arduino):**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.println(Serial.read()); //this print the byte received
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code that you are using. Thanks

Comment: @StayOnTarget thank you for reply, i did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the code necesarily has to start with a string as its input, if what you really want is to send numeric values. But assuming that is the case, you probably can use the `Chr()` function to encode other values as individual characters.

The question asked about 0 or 1... so you could do:

```
s = Chr(0)
send_string handle, s
```

From this, `s` will be a string. It won't contain a printable character (0 in ASCII does not represent any letter, numeral, punctuation, etc.) but that doesn't matter.

`Chr` should work fine for values 0-255.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function)

Comment: thank you very much! this function works fine, looks simple but help me out of cage. i really glad to invite you a cup of coffee :)

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful!